# Netconf: Not able to perform getConfig()

Tags: java, ietf-netconf

We have a netconf enabled router and I am able to perform get/get-config operations using Mg-Soft client browser. This is the output of getConfig() -

REQ:

```
<nc:get-config xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <nc:source>
    <nc:running/>
  </nc:source>
</nc:get-config>
```

RESP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <configure xmlns="urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf">
    <qos>
      <sap-ingress>
      .....
</data>
```

But I am unable to perform the same operation using tailf Netconf client.
Here is my code -

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws JNCException, 
            ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

        DeviceUser deviceUser;
        String deviceUserName = "user";
        deviceUser = new DeviceUser(deviceUserName, "admin", "admin");
        Device device = new Device("simulator", deviceUser, "10.135.16.13", 830);
        device.connect(deviceUserName);
        device.newSession(new Subscriber("simulator"), "mySession");
        NetconfSession session = device.getSession("mySession");

        NodeSet config = session.getConfig(NetconfSession.RUNNING);
        String xmlString = config.toXMLString();
        session.closeSession();
        System.out.println(xmlString);
    }
}

class Subscriber extends IOSubscriber {
    String devName;
    public static boolean rawMode = false;
    Subscriber(String devName) {
        super(rawMode);
        this.devName = devName;
    }
    public void input(String data) {
        System.out.println("RECV: " + data);
    }

    public void output(String data) {
        System.out.println("SEND: " + data);
    }
}
```

I am getting the following in the eclipse console -

```
SEND: <hello xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <capabilities>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:base:1.0</capability>
  </capabilities>
</hello>

RECV: <hello xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
  <capabilities>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:base:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:base:1.1</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:writable-running:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:candidate:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:validate:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:validate:1.1</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:startup:1.0</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:url:1.0?scheme=ftp,tftp,file</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:netconf:capability:with-defaults:1.0?basic-mode=trim&amp;also-supported=report-all</capability>
    <capability>urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0?module=ietf-netconf&amp;revision=2011-06-01&amp;features=writable-running,validate,startup,url&amp;deviations=alu-netconf-deviations-r13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:netconf-deviations-r13?module=alu-netconf-deviations-r13&amp;revision=2015-01-23</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:cli-content-layer-r13?module=alu-cli-content-layer-r13&amp;revision=2015-01-23</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-r13?module=alu-conf-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-24</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-aaa-r13?module=alu-conf-aaa-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-aa-r13?module=alu-conf-aa-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-23</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-calltrace-r13?module=alu-conf-calltrace-r13&amp;revision=2016-04-27</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-card-r13?module=alu-conf-card-r13&amp;revision=2015-10-30</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-cflowd-r13?module=alu-conf-cflowd-r13&amp;revision=2015-01-26</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-conn-prof-r13?module=alu-conf-conn-prof-r13&amp;revision=2015-11-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-con-profvlan-r13?module=alu-conf-con-profvlan-r13&amp;revision=2015-08-28</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-eth-cfm-r13?module=alu-conf-eth-cfm-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-eth-ring-r13?module=alu-conf-eth-ring-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-17</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-eth-tunnel-r13?module=alu-conf-eth-tunnel-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-filter-r13?module=alu-conf-filter-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-gmpls-tunnel-r13?module=alu-conf-gmpls-tunnel-r13&amp;revision=2014-12-09</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-ifgrphandler-r13?module=alu-conf-ifgrphandler-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-isa-r13?module=alu-conf-isa-r13&amp;revision=2016-02-29</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-lag-r13?module=alu-conf-lag-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-li-r13?module=alu-conf-li-r13&amp;revision=2016-04-21</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-log-r13?module=alu-conf-log-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-01</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-mcastmgmt-r13?module=alu-conf-mcastmgmt-r13&amp;revision=2015-03-12</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-mirror-r13?module=alu-conf-mirror-r13&amp;revision=2016-01-08</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-oam-pm-r13?module=alu-conf-oam-pm-r13&amp;revision=2015-11-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-open-flow-r13?module=alu-conf-open-flow-r13&amp;revision=2015-11-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-r13?module=alu-conf-port-r13&amp;revision=2015-08-27</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-access-r13?module=alu-conf-port-access-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-31</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-aps-r13?module=alu-conf-port-aps-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-ethernet-r13?module=alu-conf-port-ethernet-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-mbundle-r13?module=alu-conf-port-mbundle-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-network-r13?module=alu-conf-port-network-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-sonetsdh-r13?module=alu-conf-port-sonetsdh-r13&amp;revision=2015-06-11</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-tdm-r13?module=alu-conf-port-tdm-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-tdm-ds1-r13?module=alu-conf-port-tdm-ds1-r13&amp;revision=2014-12-15</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-tdm-ds3-r13?module=alu-conf-port-tdm-ds3-r13&amp;revision=2014-12-15</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-tdm-e1-r13?module=alu-conf-port-tdm-e1-r13&amp;revision=2014-12-15</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-tdm-e3-r13?module=alu-conf-port-tdm-e3-r13&amp;revision=2014-12-15</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-port-policy-r13?module=alu-conf-port-policy-r13&amp;revision=2015-12-09</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-pxc-r13?module=alu-conf-pxc-r13&amp;revision=2015-04-24</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-python-r13?module=alu-conf-python-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-qos-r13?module=alu-conf-qos-r13&amp;revision=2016-04-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-redundancy-r13?module=alu-conf-redundancy-r13&amp;revision=2016-03-25</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-r13?module=alu-conf-router-r13&amp;revision=2016-05-09</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-bgp-r13?module=alu-conf-router-bgp-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-06</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-dhcps-r13?module=alu-conf-router-dhcps-r13&amp;revision=2015-09-21</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-dhcp6-r13?module=alu-conf-router-dhcp6-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-fspec-r13?module=alu-conf-router-fspec-r13&amp;revision=2015-12-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-gmpls-r13?module=alu-conf-router-gmpls-r13&amp;revision=2015-11-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-igmp-r13?module=alu-conf-router-igmp-r13&amp;revision=2015-11-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-if-r13?module=alu-conf-router-if-r13&amp;revision=2016-04-29</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-isis-r13?module=alu-conf-router-isis-r13&amp;revision=2016-02-18</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-l2tp-r13?module=alu-conf-router-l2tp-r13&amp;revision=2016-05-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-ldp-r13?module=alu-conf-router-ldp-r13&amp;revision=2016-05-02</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-lmp-r13?module=alu-conf-router-lmp-r13&amp;revision=2015-09-08</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-mccacpl-r13?module=alu-conf-router-mccacpl-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-mld-r13?module=alu-conf-router-mld-r13&amp;revision=2015-09-22</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-mpls-r13?module=alu-conf-router-mpls-r13&amp;revision=2016-04-28</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-mpls-tp-r13?module=alu-conf-router-mpls-tp-r13&amp;revision=2015-11-09</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-nat-r13?module=alu-conf-router-nat-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-ogvalid-r13?module=alu-conf-router-ogvalid-r13&amp;revision=2015-11-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-ospf-r13?module=alu-conf-router-ospf-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-22</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-ospf3-r13?module=alu-conf-router-ospf3-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-22</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-pcep-r13?module=alu-conf-router-pcep-r13&amp;revision=2016-03-07</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-pim-r13?module=alu-conf-router-pim-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-07</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-policy-r13?module=alu-conf-router-policy-r13&amp;revision=2016-05-19</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-radprox-r13?module=alu-conf-router-radprox-r13&amp;revision=2015-11-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-rip-r13?module=alu-conf-router-rip-r13&amp;revision=2015-06-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-nhroute-r13?module=alu-conf-router-nhroute-r13&amp;revision=2014-09-26</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-radvert-r13?module=alu-conf-router-radvert-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-rsvp-r13?module=alu-conf-router-rsvp-r13&amp;revision=2015-06-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-wlan-r13?module=alu-conf-router-wlan-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-router-wpp-r13?module=alu-conf-router-wpp-r13&amp;revision=2015-03-04</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-saa-r13?module=alu-conf-saa-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-service-r13?module=alu-conf-service-r13&amp;revision=2016-03-23</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-apipe-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-apipe-r13&amp;revision=2016-02-26</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-cpipe-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-cpipe-r13&amp;revision=2016-02-26</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-cust-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-cust-r13&amp;revision=2015-09-23</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-dynsrv-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-dynsrv-r13&amp;revision=2015-09-11</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-egrmcgroup-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-egrmcgroup-r13&amp;revision=2015-09-11</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-epipe-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-epipe-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-27</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-fpipe-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-fpipe-r13&amp;revision=2016-02-26</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-ies-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-ies-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-ies-if-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-ies-if-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-27</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-ies-subif-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-ies-subif-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-ipfix-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-ipfix-r13&amp;revision=2014-09-26</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-ipipe-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-ipipe-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-nat-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-nat-r13&amp;revision=2016-04-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-sdp-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-sdp-r13&amp;revision=2016-05-09</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-template-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-template-r13&amp;revision=2016-04-06</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-upnp-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-upnp-r13&amp;revision=2015-09-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-igmp-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-igmp-r13&amp;revision=2014-09-26</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-macmo-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-macmo-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-macpr-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-macpr-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-meshs-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-meshs-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-mld-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-mld-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-pim-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-pim-r13&amp;revision=2015-07-07</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-sap-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-sap-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-27</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-split-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-split-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-spoke-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-spoke-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-13</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-spb-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-spb-r13&amp;revision=2016-02-04</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vpls-stp-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vpls-stp-r13&amp;revision=2014-09-26</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-bgp-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-bgp-r13&amp;revision=2016-05-04</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-dhcps-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-dhcps-r13&amp;revision=2015-09-21</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-dhcp6-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-dhcp6-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-fspec-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-fspec-r13&amp;revision=2016-02-11</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-igmp-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-igmp-r13&amp;revision=2015-11-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-if-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-if-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-27</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-isis-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-isis-r13&amp;revision=2016-02-18</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-l2tp-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-l2tp-r13&amp;revision=2016-05-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-mld-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-mld-r13&amp;revision=2015-10-14</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-nat-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-nat-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-nwif-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-nwif-r13&amp;revision=2016-04-29</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svs-vprn-ntp-r13?module=alu-conf-svs-vprn-ntp-r13&amp;revision=2015-05-05</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-ospf-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-ospf-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-22</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-ospf3-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-ospf3-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-22</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-pim-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-pim-r13&amp;revision=2015-08-17</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-ptp-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-ptp-r13&amp;revision=2015-05-22</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-vprn-radprox-r13?module=alu-conf-vprn-radprox-r13&amp;revision=2015-06-23</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-rip-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-rip-r13&amp;revision=2015-06-03</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-ripng-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-ripng-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-radv-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-radv-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-srcad-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-srcad-r13&amp;revision=2015-01-27</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-spoke-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-spoke-r13&amp;revision=2015-12-17</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-subif-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-subif-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-wlan-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-wlan-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-svc-vprn-wpp-r13?module=alu-conf-svc-vprn-wpp-r13&amp;revision=2015-03-04</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-sflow-r13?module=alu-conf-sflow-r13&amp;revision=2014-09-26</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-sfm-r13?module=alu-conf-sfm-r13&amp;revision=2014-10-20</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-subscrmgmt-r13?module=alu-conf-subscrmgmt-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-27</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-submgmt-ludb-r13?module=alu-conf-submgmt-ludb-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-14</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-submgmt-wlangw-r13?module=alu-conf-submgmt-wlangw-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-system-r13?module=alu-conf-system-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-08</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-sys-pwrmgmt-r13?module=alu-conf-sys-pwrmgmt-r13&amp;revision=2015-05-25</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-sys-ptp-r13?module=alu-conf-sys-ptp-r13&amp;revision=2015-06-25</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-sys-sec-r13?module=alu-conf-sys-sec-r13&amp;revision=2016-06-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-vrrp-r13?module=alu-conf-vrrp-r13&amp;revision=2015-10-14</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:conf-vsm-r13?module=alu-conf-vsm-r13&amp;revision=2015-09-16</capability>
    <capability>urn:alcatel-lucent.com:sros:ns:yang:types?module=alu-types&amp;revision=2015-01-19</capability>
    <capability>urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:conf?module=nokia-conf&amp;revision=2016-01-01</capability>
    <capability>urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:sros-yang-extensions?module=nokia-sros-yang-extensions&amp;revision=2016-01-01</capability>
    <capability>urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:types-filter?module=nokia-types-filter&amp;revision=2016-01-01</capability>
    <capability>urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:types-qos?module=nokia-types-qos&amp;revision=2016-01-01</capability>
    <capability>urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:types-services?module=nokia-types-services&amp;revision=2016-01-01</capability>
    <capability>urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:types-sros?module=nokia-types-sros&amp;revision=2016-01-01</capability>
    <capability>urn:nokia.com:sros:ns:yang:sr:major-release-14</capability>
  </capabilities>
  <session-id>52</session-id>
</hello>

SEND: <nc:rpc xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" nc:message-id="1">
  <nc:get-config>
    <nc:source>
      <nc:running/>    </nc:source>
  </nc:get-config>
</nc:rpc>

RECV: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc-reply urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0:message-id="1" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <rpc-error>
        <error-type>rpc</error-type>
        <error-tag>missing-attribute</error-tag>
        <error-severity>error</error-severity>
        <error-info>
            <bad-element>message-id</bad-element>
            <bad-element>rpc</bad-element>
        </error-info>
        <error-message>
            Check that message-id attribute is present and less than 4096 characters
        </error-message>
    </rpc-error>
</rpc-reply>

[Fatal Error] :2:20: Attribute name "urn:ietf" associated with an element type "rpc-reply" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
[Fatal Error] :2:20: Attribute name "urn:ietf" associated with an element type "rpc-reply" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 20; Attribute name "urn:ietf" associated with an element type "rpc-reply" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1239)
    at com.tailf.jnc.YangXMLParser.parse(YangXMLParser.java:50)
    at com.tailf.jnc.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:154)
    at com.tailf.jnc.NetconfSession.recv_rpc_reply(NetconfSession.java:1495)
    at com.tailf.jnc.NetconfSession.recv_rpc_reply_data(NetconfSession.java:1472)
    at com.tailf.jnc.NetconfSession.getConfig(NetconfSession.java:443)
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:51)
Exception in thread "main" Parse error: parse error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 20; Attribute name "urn:ietf" associated with an element type "rpc-reply" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
    at com.tailf.jnc.YangXMLParser.parse(YangXMLParser.java:54)
    at com.tailf.jnc.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:154)
    at com.tailf.jnc.NetconfSession.recv_rpc_reply(NetconfSession.java:1495)
    at com.tailf.jnc.NetconfSession.recv_rpc_reply_data(NetconfSession.java:1472)
    at com.tailf.jnc.NetconfSession.getConfig(NetconfSession.java:443)
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:51)
```

Comment: In the console output, the `<rpc-reply urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0:message-id="1"` is erroneous. This is also reported by your reply parser. Note that different NETCONF clients may have different message parsing tolerance, meaning what is recognized as an error in one, may not be in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually seem to have two problems, neither of which appear to be your fault. The get-config request from JNC seems to be malformed: `message-id` attribute should be in the default namespace, not in NETCONF message namespace.

```
SEND: <nc:rpc xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" nc:message-id="1">
  <nc:get-config>
    <nc:source>
      <nc:running/>    </nc:source>
  </nc:get-config>
</nc:rpc>
```

Should actually be:

```
SEND: <nc:rpc xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" message-id="1">
  <nc:get-config>
    <nc:source>
      <nc:running/>    </nc:source>
  </nc:get-config>
</nc:rpc>
```

The second problem is your server, which appears to be unable to handle this malformed request - and is responding with a malformed message (it is not even an XML message):

```
RECV: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc-reply urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0:message-id="1" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <rpc-error>
        <error-type>rpc</error-type>
        <error-tag>missing-attribute</error-tag>
        <error-severity>error</error-severity>
        <error-info>
            <bad-element>message-id</bad-element>
            <bad-element>rpc</bad-element>
        </error-info>
        <error-message>
            Check that message-id attribute is present and less than 4096 characters
        </error-message>
    </rpc-error>
</rpc-reply>
```

It should be responding with:

```
RECV: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rpc-reply nc:message-id="1" xmlns:nc="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
    <rpc-error>
        <error-type>rpc</error-type>
        <error-tag>missing-attribute</error-tag>
        <error-severity>error</error-severity>
        <error-info>
            <bad-element>message-id</bad-element>
            <bad-element>rpc</bad-element>
        </error-info>
        <error-message>
            Check that message-id attribute is present and less than 4096 characters
        </error-message>
    </rpc-error>
</rpc-reply>
```

since it is supposed to return all attributes verbatim. Otherwise, this would be standard behavior when a message without a `message-id` attribute is sent to a server.

Relevant RFC4741 text below (the same applies to RFC6241, NETCONF 1.1).

[Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4741#section-4.1):

> The <rpc> element has a mandatory attribute "message-id", which is an
> arbitrary string chosen by the sender of the RPC that will commonly
> encode a monotonically increasing integer.  The receiver of the RPC
> does not decode or interpret this string but simply saves it to be
> used as a "message-id" attribute in any resulting <rpc-reply>
> message.  For example:
>
> `<rpc message-id="101"
> xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
> <some-method>
> <!-- method parameters here... -->
> </some-method>
> </rpc>`
>
> If additional attributes are present in an <rpc> element, a NETCONF
> peer MUST return them unmodified in the <rpc-reply> element.

[Section 4.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4741#section-4.3)

> An error is returned if an <rpc> element is received without a
> message-id attribute.  Note that only in this case is it
> acceptable for the NETCONF peer to omit the message-id attribute
> in the <rpc-reply> element.
>
> `<rpc xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
> <get-config>
> <source>
>   <running/>
> </source>
> </get-config>
> </rpc>`
>
> `<rpc-reply xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:netconf:base:1.0">
> <rpc-error>
> <error-type>rpc</error-type>
> <error-tag>missing-attribute</error-tag>
> <error-severity>error</error-severity>
> <error-info>
>   <bad-attribute>message-id</bad-attribute>
>   <bad-element>rpc</bad-element>
> </error-info>
> </rpc-error>
> </rpc-reply>`

So I believe you should be reporting two issues to both the maker of the device and to creators of JNC.

The reason it is working with the MG-SOFT client is that it sends a proper `message-id` attribute, so your case never happens.

Comment: Hi @predi, thanks a ton for answering in all possible details! I am really really grateful to you! Now I understand the real issue. My task is to make the client request work with the particular server. Now I can't change the server response even if it is not totally netconf compatible. So I need to modify the JNC library to make the both ends meet. The client should only query for get-config and parse the response properly.  Again, I am really thankful for explaining everything in such details.

Comment: Hi @predi, it's now working! You nailed it! I modified the NetconfSession.java and modified line 1618 as follows -

`//out.print("<" + nc + "rpc " + xmlnsAttr + " " + nc + "message-id=\"");
out.print("<" + nc + "rpc " + xmlnsAttr + " " + "message-id=\"");`

I have removed the erroneous nc tag and bingo. I am able to send get-config to the router and get reply. My sincere thanks for such a quick analysis! Take a bow. Now I will raise an issue with JNC.

Comment: Glad I could help.